# Parse String on Button Click to Activity

Tags: string, parsing, android-activity

I want to parse a String (link) to another activity, when a button in a ListView is clicked.
The ListView ist populated by JSON (fetched MySQL-Data).

What's the trick to send the 'link' to the other activity, when I press a button in the ListView?

So far I tried searching for XML Form submit... but I think this is not the right way, I think to much in the direction of programming html forms...

my ListView (populated dynamically)

```
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/link"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="82dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/videobutton"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
                android:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

What I now want to do is to get the populated 'link' from the TextView in my new activity.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are clicking a list item and navigate to another activity with required String(link) as you explained. For this purpose, try this.

On list item click, call activity intent like

```
 Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("link","PUT YOUR LINK HERE");
 startActivity(i);
```